# Is there a way to check if a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C} $ is separable? i.e $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ where g,h are nontrivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

I have a iterative process for applying steepest descent/saddle point approximation to functions of several complex variables. It only really works if the function is separable, though. the function in question  $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic in both variables on the domain (it's actually entire for the current function I'm working with, I'm not sure if this would make a difference).

Is there some way to test if it's possible to test for separability, or make some deformation/transform to enable this?

Formally, I want to define separability roughly as follows: for $f:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}$, f separable if 
$$f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$$ Where $g,h$ are not constant (unless $\frac{d}{dx} f=0/\frac{d}{dy}f=0$ on the domain )

Further question: so, maybe a function will not be separable in x,y. However, is there a way to construct/determine constructability of $u,v=u(x,y),v(x,y)$ such that $f(u,v) $ is separable?

Comment: Assume $f \ne 0$ over some open set, in order for $f$ to be separable, it need to satisfy a PDE: $$\require{cancel}
\begin{align} f = gh \implies  &\log f = \log g + \log h\\ 
\implies & \partial_x\partial_y \log f = 
\partial_x \color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{\partial_y \log g}}} + 
\partial_y \color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{\partial_x \log h}}} = 0\\
\iff & f \partial_x\partial_y f - \partial_x f \partial_y f = 0\end{align}$$

Comment: @achillehui thanks this is great. Is there an extension of this to allow for the case of first applying a transform to x and y?

Comment: No idea, my knowledge on this is minimal.